# Cant receive Post Data to gcloud flask api from fetch function in react app

Tags: python, google-cloud-run, flask-restful

I have a very simple api that is written in Flask and deployed to cloud cloud run.
I am collecting data from the client and passing it to a cloud run flask api, and once flask receives the post request json object, it needs to restructure the data and send it to a third-party payment processing app.
I'm a MERN developer, don't really know python, just REST and HTTP so Ive been debugging for days and im absolutely stuck. any help would be awesome.
here is my react fetch request:

```
    let items = [];
    cartItems.forEach((cartItem) => {
      let itemObject = {
        strainTitle: cartItem.title,
        quantity: cartItem.quantity,
      };
      items.push(itemObject)
    });

    let orderSummary = {
      total: total + shipping + tax,
      s1,
      s2,
      fname: firstName,
      lname: lastName,
      phone: phoneNumber,
      memo: `confirmation email sent to ${email}`,
      email,
      city,
      state: stateOfResidence,
      addy,
      zipcode: zipCode,
      items,
    };

    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
    };
    options.body = JSON.stringify(orderSummary)

    fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_SEAMLESS_URL,
      options
    )
      
      .then((response) => response.body)
      .then((body) => {
        const reader = body.getReader();

        return new ReadableStream({
          start(controller) {
            return pump();

            function pump() {
              return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
                if (done) {
                  controller.close();
                  return;
                }

                // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
                controller.enqueue(value);
                return pump();
              });
            }
          },
        });
      })

      .then((stream) => new Response(stream))
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          clearCart();
          history.push("/");
        }
      });

    // { type: "POST", data: cart }).then(response => console.log(response))
  };
```

and here is my app.py:

```
def index(path):
        # GET request
        if request.method == 'GET':
                   return {
        "loaded": True,
        "val": "Flask Api running in the cloud"
        }
        # POST request
        if request.method == 'POST':
                data = request.get_json(force=True)
                total = data.get("orderSummary").get("total")
                r = data.get("orderSummary").get("s1")
                ac = data.get("orderSummary").get("s2")
                fname =data.get("orderSummary").get("fname")
                lname = data.get("orderSummary").get("lname")
                memo = data.get("orderSummary").get("memo")
                city = data.get("orderSummary").get("city")
                state = data.get("orderSummary").get("state")
                zipcode = data.get("orderSummary").get("zipcode")
                addy = data.get("orderSummary").get("addy")
                email = data.get("orderSummary").get("email")
                items = data.get("orderSummary").get("items")
                phone_number = data.get("orderSummary").get("phone")
                logging.info(data)
                logging.info(total, r, ac, fname, lname, memo, city, state, zipcode, addy, email, items, phone_number)

                app.config.from_pyfile('./settings.py')
                load_dotenv('.env')
                url = 'https://sandbox.seamlesschex.com/v1/check/create'
                payload = json.dumps({
                        "number": random.randint(1,999999), 
                "email": email, 
                "authorization_date": date.today(), 
                        "label": "Thank you from Chubby's",
                        "address": addy,
                        "city": city,
                        "state": state,
                        "zip": zipcode,
                        "phone": phone_number,
                        "bank_account": ac,
                        "bank_routing": r,
                        "name": fname + " " + lname,
                        "memo": memo,
                        "amount": total,
        }, separators=(',', ':'), default=str)

                headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': app.config.get("SEAMLESS_SANDBOX_KEY")
                        }

                response = requests.request('POST', url, headers = headers,
                data = payload, allow_redirects=False, timeout=1000000000)
                data = response.json()
                checkDATA = data['check']
                if checkDATA:
                        from flask import Flask, jsonify
                        from flask_mail import Mail, Message

                        mail_settings = {
                        "MAIL_SERVER": app.config.get("EMAIL_SERVER"),
                        "MAIL_PORT": 465,
                        "MAIL_USE_TLS": False,
                        "MAIL_USE_SSL": True,
                        "MAIL_USERNAME": app.config.get("EMAIL_ACCT"),
                        "MAIL_PASSWORD": app.config.get("EMAIL_PWD")
                        }
                        app.config.update(mail_settings)
                        mail = Mail(app)
                        with app.app_context():
                                msgToCustomer = Message(subject="Successful Order Initiation With Chubbys Seed Supply Co.", sender=app.config.get("EMAIL_ACCT"), recipients=[email], body="The Biggest Chubbys' thank you is sent to you today. We recived your order today and are dilligently processing your order and getting it all packaged up nice and neat and safe. Be on the lookout in your inbox for an email with the traking number. We'll send you an email with the tracking number once the Post Office has your package and it's on the way :). Thank you and have a great day. ")
                                mail.send(msgToCustomer)
                                msgToChubbys = Message(subject="NEW_ORDER_NEEDS TO BE FULLFILLED", sender=app.config.get("EMAIL_ACCT"), recipients=[app.config.get("EMAIL_ACCTT")], body=f"New order for {fname} {lname}. The order total is {total} and the order consists of the following items {items}. Send to {addy} {city} {state} {zipcode}. Send tracking number to {email} ")
                                mail.send(msgToChubbys)
                        return json.dumps(checkDATA)
```

here is the error im receiving in google cloud:
`File "/app/app.py", line 39, in index total = data.get("orderSummary").get("total") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python code is attempting to read in the data from your front-end as if it were in this shape:

```json
{
    "orderSummary": {
        "total": ...,
        "s1": ...,
        "s2": ...,
        ...
    }
}
```

However, the data you are sending looks as if it is in this shape:

```json
{
    "total": ...,
    "s1": ...,
    "s2": ...,
    ...
}
```

Note that there is no `orderSummary` property in the top-level object, so `data.get("orderSummary")` will return `None`, and so calling `.get(...)` on that will give you the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Try removing all of the calls to `.get("orderSummary")`:

```py
                total = data.get("total")
                r = data.get("s1")
                ac = data.get("s2")
                # and similarly for other lines...
```

---

I note also you have a line `logging.info(data)`, below all of the lines that pull values out of `data`. That's maybe not the most useful place for it, because if `data` isn't in the shape you expect it to be, it's likely that an exception will be raised before the logging line is reached and so you don't find out what shape the data is actually in. Instead, try logging `data` just after you receive it: that way, you can see the exact shape of the data you're getting, regardless of whether it's as you expect.

Comment: the ```logging.info(data)``` line was pure debugging in the browser

Comment: how would you reccomend accessing this property in the flask api: 
```items: [{strainTitle: "Purple Silverback", quantity: 9}]```

Comment: @RobertZobrist: I'm not sure I entirely understand, but I would expect `data.get("items")` to return a list containing a dict with two properties in it.

Comment: okay, yeah that was my question and that is exactly what was needed, thanks. 
Its working locally(but then again so what the previous apiPost handler in the app.py with orderSummary.get) im assuming this is because the react app and the app.py are in the same directory locally, and deployed that is not the case, right?

Comment: im in the middle of deploying it to cloudRun right now to see if this is the magic I needed :)

Comment: @RobertZobrist: to be honest, I don't know. I've never used Google Cloud nor Flask. I based my answer off some Python experience along with a basic understanding of what should be in the POST request header and how I assume Flask would handle it.

Comment: thanks man!! my api is deployed to the cloud and wow, thanks so much man. I needed to use stack overflow as a standup, like, yes, I am blocked and I need help